# gVim and 2D array

Tags: arrays, regex, vim, teststand

In my programming environment I have quite big 2D array. Its size is 90x40.

I have to fill this array by loading the data from external file.

The mechanism of loading the data consists of a binding file in which I have to do the binding in style like below:

```
Array[0][0] =
Array[0][1] =
Array[0][2] =
...
Array[20][37] = 
Array[20][38] =
...
Array[89][38] =
Array[89][39] =
```

It easy to compute that I have to create 3600 partially unique lines.

I thought that I can create the [..][..] elements in gVim and then add in front of them the name of the array. Although adding prefix is easy, I stuck on creating [..][..] bit.

In my scenario I want to solve this by doing something like:

1. create 3600 rows
2. add at the end of the each row/line (by using the `:%s/$/\[ -- my expression 1 -- \]/g` command) numbers from 0 to 89 in blocks of forty elements (forty zeros, forty ones, forty twos, etc.)
3. add at the end of the each row/line (by using the `:%s/$/\[ -- my expression  2-- \]/g` command) numbers from 0 to 39 in blocks of forty elements (zero, one, two, ..., thirty nine, zero, one, ...,etc.)

*my expression 1* would evaluate to the quotient of the operation `(number of line) mod 90`

*my expression 2* would evaluate to the reminder of the operation `(number of line) mod 40`

And the questions now are:

1. how to evaluate `(number of line)`
2. how to calculate the `(number of line) mod XX` expression?
3. maybe there is a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following in command mode if you don't want to do it with regex:

```
for i in range(0, 89) | for j in range(0, 39) | put = 'Array['.i.']['.j.'] =' | endfor | endfor
```

Answer (score 2):

VIM Macros are a better solution for this. You should write `Array[0][0]` on the first line, start recording a macro with `qq`, then `yyp` (copy and paste line), `2f[l` to place the cursor on the second array index, press `<C-a>` to increment the number under cursor by 1 and then `q` to stop recording. Once you've done this just hit `38@q` to repeat the macro 38 times to build the complete list.

Then you start recording a macro again with `qq` then `39k` to go 39 lines up and `V39jy39jp` to select, copy and paste 39 lines then `0f[l` to get to the first array index `<C-v>39j` to block select the first index `<C-a>` to increment it by one and `q` to end recording. Now hit `88@q` to repeat the last step 88 times to get the desired output.

NOTE: The execution of the macro, especially the last one `88@q`, will take sometime, so you'll have to be patient.

For the sake of completeness however, I'd like to mention how expression 1 be done. `:%s/$/\=(line('.') - 1) % 90` and similarly for expression 2

Comment: Dhruva, thanks for your answer. Regarding the completeness: the '%' function. When I can receive the quotient and when the remainder of the '%' operation?

Comment: `\=` is special for :substitute command, check `:h sub-replace-expression`. `(line('.')-1) % 90` gives you the mod (remainder) of dividing `(line('.')-1)` [current line-1] and 90.

Comment: And what can get me the quotient?

Comment: `(line('.')-1) / 90)`